# inodeへの参照（ハードリンク）が無くなると、そのinodeは削除されますか？

Tags: linux, unix, filesystems

ハードリンクは既存のiノードを参照するディレクトリエントリを追加する事と習いました。
例えば
ln foo.txt bar.txtとすると、
foo.txtとbar.txtは同じiノードを参照する事になります。

ここでrm foo.txtとした場合、bar.txtは既存のiノードを参照している状態だと思います。

さらにbar.txtを削除した場合は参照元のiノードも削除されるということで合っていますか？

1つわからなかったのがiノード自体はファイルの長さ、モード、iノード番号などの情報しか持っていないようですが、foo.txtとbar.txtの中に記述されているデータはfoo.txtとbar.txtが別々で持っているということなのでしょうか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

foo.txt と bar.txt 同じデータを参照しています。

次のように考えるとイメージがつかみやすいと思います。

- i-node → ファイルの実体
- foo.txt や bar.txt → i-nodeへのリンク

同じ i-node を指している ２つのハードリンクは、リンク先の実体が同じものですので、全く同じデータが参照されます。

また、i-nodeには ハードリンクの数を表すカウント情報が含まれています。
この、カウントが 0 になると iノードは削除されます。（つまりファイルが削除されます）

Linux で `ls -il` を実行すると i-node番号 と リンク数が表示することができます。
試していただくと foo.txtとbar.txtは同じ i-node番号、リンク数が表示されるはずです。

また、新たに作成したファイルは、ハードリンク数が 1 であることが確認出来ます。
つまり普通のファイルはカウント数 1 の ハードリンクなのです。

Answer (score 2):

> さらにbar.txtを削除した場合は参照元のiノードも削除されるということで合っていますか？

はい。

> 1つわからなかったのがiノード自体はファイルの長さ、モード、iノード番号などの情報しか持っていないようですが、

これはVFSでのiノードの定義のことを言っているものと思います。各ファイルシステムではVFSでの定義をもとに、データ情報などファイルシステム固有の情報を含んだiノードを定義しています。